# Simple code for polarizable force-field molecular dynamics?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, software-recommendations, databases, forcefields, polarizability

I am interested in writing my own molecular dynamics code that uses a polarizable force-field. I am wondering if there are relatively simple "toy repositories" for these models such as is very common for pairwise FF's. The [Allen-Tildesly](https://github.com/Allen-Tildesley/examples/tree/master/python_examples) python/fortran GIT repo is an excellent example for pair-wise additive models.

There are three types of polarizable force-fields that meet the criteria that I am after:

1. atomic multipoles
2. drude oscillators
3. fluctuating charge models.

What these have in common is an underlying pairwise additive force-field that in addition accounts for the many body contribution from polarizability.

This is all under the molecular mechanics umbrella, not ab-initio or more rigorous. A well written code should be able to sample in the nano-seconds per day for thousands of molecules, on 12 or less cpus, with the type of polarizable model I am after.